# How to share Visualforce page (<apex:page/>) controller with multiple child components (<c:componentName/>)

Tags: visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

I have a Visualforce page that is essentially a form with 8 steps. It uses a custom controller. I have recently moved each step into it's own component (8 in total). Now what I am wondering is, can I use the visualforce page controller without having to call the controller again within each one of my components. When I call the controller in each component I receive the error: 'System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101'. when I omit the controller all together I also receive an error. The SOQL error was not present before I moved each step into it's own component.

Comment: You could send the data from the visualforce page to the child components using attributes.

Answer (score 4):

I typically do this with the page controller directly:

```
<apex:page controller="XYZ">
  <c:comp1 controller="{!self}" />
  <c:comp2 controller="{!self}" />
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class XYZ {
  public XYZ getSelf() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

---

```
<apex:component controller="ABC">
  <apex:attribute assignTo="{!pageController}" name="controller" type="XYZ" required="true" />
  ...
</apex:component>
```

---

```
public class ABC {
  public XYZ pageController { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

---

This design can allow you to share data between all the components, typical if you're building a multi-page wizard, for example.

Comment: @MAS89 I typed this from memory, might a typo somewhere. Check the docs for more info. I'll see if I can find a working version in my code base.

Comment: sfdcfox, in your answer you mentioned a multi-page wizard. I am curious if there are open examples of this on the Internet. I am building one and I am struggling with finding best practices on this.

Comment: @Eduard I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/ea31085d6cae1ca78ba643aaff93fa7d) (had to fix from previous one, had typos) that demonstrates the techniques outlined in this answer. The controller has the shared logic, and each component can access the data/methods. This is a super-simple example, but it does copy-paste well, so go ahead and check it out.

Comment: sfdcfox, please bare with me one more question. In your example, data and methods from the controller are shared with components. In this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248563/how-is-an-object-instance-passed-with-apexattribute-reflected-in-viewstate/249126#comment378856_249126) I saved the controller instance as member variable in components' controller. And this exposed weird behavior of View State. So is it really reasonable to build complex wizards when the main controller instance is passed to a component's controller?

Comment: @Eduard added an answer to your other question, but yes, you can write wizards this way; the total view state should be smaller when using references as you've done. Also, as my code demonstrates, you could always just put the logic in the main wizard controller and not use any controllers on the child components.

Comment: Thanks again! Your answers contain great value. I agree that I could use the main controller in a component without having a controller for the component. And I've so for some steps in my wizard which do not contain complex logic, like a set of input fields. However, I have a step on which I upload files. For this I certainly needed a separate controller, and it should know about the main controller, because it uses its data. Also the main reason why I used components to build a wizard was SoC so I didn't want to have everything in one controller.

Comment: @Eduard Yes, I agree that SoC is important. You can use the page-level controller strictly for data as well, and each component can have their own controller. The demo I wrote is primarily for, well, demonstration purposes. You seem to have a firm grasp on what your project needs now, so feel free to adjust the pattern as necessary.